# Office.js - Inserting table rows in a content control results in errors

Tags: ms-word, office-js

When I manually (or via office.js code) insert rows into a table that is in a content control, it increases the number of content controls in the contentControls collection.  Word 2016 Windows version 1611.

For example, if I have 1 table in 1 content control, initially the contentControls.items.length = 1.  If I insert 3 rows, then the contentControls.items.length = 4.

```
        Word.run(function (context) {
            var contentCntrls = context.document.contentControls;
            context.load(contentCntrls, "tag");
            return context.sync().then(function () {
                app.showNotification("contentCntrls.items.length: " + contentCntrls.items.length, "");
            });
        })
```

This produces errors ("Internal Error") in subsequent code that uses the contentControls collection and eventually freezes/crashes Word.

This behavior happens with both the beta and version 1 office.js code.
The issue occurs on Windows, but works fine on Macs.

The count of content controls does not change if I check it via VBA:  Debug.Print ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Count

If the user saves changes (after inserting rows), then the issue does not occur.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?  Is there some workaround (perhaps to reset the CC collection)?

Comment: In summary: Juan determined that the issue only occurs when saving to OneDrive.  Microsoft will work on a fix (perhaps publish in June+).  A workaround may be to use the Save API to reset the Content Control collection.

Comment: Andrew, you should not be experiencing this in latest builds (16.0.11128.2000) insiders fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: The issue is fixed. (REF: 1461591)

---

Update: we found a bug on this. Happens when the document is stored in OneDrive. we are in the process of fixing it.

--------------LEAVING ORIGINAL ANSWER FOR REFERENCE ---------------------

I was trying to repro this issue, but i am not able to. I tried 2 different paths to test the scenario:

1. inserted a table, selected the whole table and manually inserted a content control.
2. inserted a content control, added a few paragraphs then a table inside.

After adding rows to the 1 and 2 tables I did not see the item.length increasing as you describe, it stayed at 1 content control.

Also there is no such thing as build 1611 for Windows. Can you please provide more details on:

1. how are you inserting the table and the content control
2. Verify the build number. I tried it in the latest publicly available build which is 16.7766.2068, make sure to update your client before testing.

thanks!

Comment: The 1611 above referred to the Office version.  I've now tested it on versions 1612 and 1701 and I'm still seeing the issue.

Comment: How are you getting the Office version?

Comment: Both of your paths above produce the issue.  The issue won't occur if the file is not saved or if you have not saved it after inserting the Content Control(s) and table(s).  So save the file with the CC and table, then insert rows (any method) and then the issue usually occurs (CC count issue).  CC count resets to correct number when you save.  I use Rich Text CCs. Let me know how else I can help.

Comment: Can you please confirm how are you getting the Office version ?

Comment: Under File > Account below Office Updates, under "Current Channel".  Perhaps the actual version is under About Word; which is 16.0.7571.7095 32-bit.  Which is the Version 1611 (Build 7571.2109).

Comment: Thanks, yes I meant build number. let  me investigate further, I did not  tried the save/no save combinations. Would be great if you can update to latest and try. We are in 16.7766 now.

Comment: Yes, I also tried on different PC that now has 16.7766.7080 (version 1701) and it has the same issues.

Comment: I tried it again, and i am still not able to repro this issue. I actually recorded a video using build 16.7766. basically i added a table, wrapped it with a content control. saved the document. then added rows to the table. then check number of cc. Its always 1.  Check video here: https://1drv.ms/v/s!Ak8vcT63v84Mh9c8QSUeP42oWKgnTw  seems to be this is a very edge case, if you can record a video with repro steps will be great. thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137611/discussion-between-excelanalyst-and-juan-balmori).